# Export only a select project from a repository with all history / revision?

Tags: svn, synchronization, repository, svnsync

I have a project in repository A and I'm setting up a new repository B.

I am currently using svnsync to synchronize two repositories in an effort to make a copy of the first and then I intend to remove the other projects leaving only mine behind.

I'm wondering if there is a better way wherein only my project in repository A is "exported" (along with ALL history / transactions).

I'm using svn 1.4.2 on the target system and I dont have much permission on the source system except a read/write account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what [`svndumpfilter`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.filtering) is designed for. If you're not able to run it directly on the repository, first let svnsync do its job until you have a complete copy, and then perform the `svnadmin dump` - `svndumpfilter` - `svnadmin load` step.

For example:

```
svnadmin dump original_repos | svndumpfilter include myproject | svnadmin load my_repos
```